# Does anybody know what this lump on my bulldog could be?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition, junior-pets, large-dogs

So my bulldog has a lump that seems to look like a wart, as it is dry on the top. It is growing, but it's causing him no discomfort. However, he has suffered with his skin a little.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If it's growing, you should get it checked by a vet.

From the position in front of the hind legs, it could be one of his nipples that is swollen. That could either point to an infection or to the equivalent of breast cancer.

If it's not a nipple, the red color could indicate an abscess or similar localized infection in the skin. In that case the infected skin is often slightly warmer than the surrounding healthy skin.

It could also be a simple, benign wart or skin polyp. But only a vet will be able to distinguish a harmless skin growth from an infection or cancer.